# Cannot import installed module inside a Python virtualenv

Tags: python, docker, pip, anaconda, setup.py

I have installed my own python package `mypackage` using `pip install .` in a dir with a `setup.py`. It seems like the package is installed, but when I tried to import it I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

See the following terminal session:

```
(venv-docker) root@71f904d6e6ed:/../scripts# pip list | grep mypackage
mypackage (0.0.3)
(venv-docker) root@71f904d6e6ed:/../scripts# which pip
/../venv-docker/bin/pip
(venv-docker) root@71f904d6e6ed:/../scripts# which python
/../venv-docker/bin/python
(venv-docker) root@71f904d6e6ed:/../scripts# python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mypackage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypackage'
```

How can this Happen?

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The installed package is a distribution, it may have several modules to import with different names than the package itself. Can you include the directory tree of the package sources?

Comment: Basically the installed package is a single "mypackage.py" file and a "setup.py" file. Nothing more. Furthermore this approach does work on another pc of mine, so I know that in principle this approach must be able to work.

Comment: `pip --version`? `pip show --files mypackage`?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose videoset is a module inside mypackage

```
from <package_name>  import <module_name>
```

Comment: Ah no, changed videoset to 'mypackage' to make it general. Just did not see that line. The answer is now edited to fix this.